# Lua on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, lua

Is it possible to use Lua with Google App Engine? I recognize that there will be a lot of Java glue, but I would like to use Lua for most of the logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible with a port of Lua such as [Kahlua](http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/) or [Jill](http://code.google.com/p/jillcode/) (Lua implemented in Java).  The [Lua Users Wiki page on Lua Implementations](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations) does not show any ports written in Python.

But you wouldn't be able to use "vanilla" Lua because that is written in C; as you're probably aware, GAE only allows Java and Python code.

Comment: My eyes are also on [LuaJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/ "LuaJ")--is that a decent option as well? The biggest challenge that I see is bringing the server environment variables, etc. into Lua.

Comment: @geekpreacher: LuaJ might be a good one too.  It's designed to run on J2SE, and it [has a LuaJava library](http://luaforge.net/docman/view.php/457/5688/README.html) that you can use to bind Java classes into Lua.  That would simplify things for your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [Lunatic Python](http://labix.org/lunatic-python) purports to be a way to run Lua in Python or vice versa.  If that's true, then you could use their tools to create a Lua interpreter running in a Python app running on Google App Engine.  Sounds promising.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately Lunatic Python requires compiling a C module, and that's not possible in Google App Engine.