# how to access datastore in google cloud by lua

Tags: lua, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access google cloud by lua but I cannot find out the google cloud library for lua, like google.datastore.entity.

Does anyone know of one?

thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported Cloud Client Libraries are provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries), unfortunately Lua is not supported at this time. However, you might be able to use one of the Lua interpreters implemented in Java as mention in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011192/lua-on-google-app-engine#answer-3011200) and the comments below.